# How to make a php variable work in javascript

Tags: javascript, php, html

```
<script>
function selectinventory(){
var inventorychoice = document.getElementById("selection").value;
if (inventorychoice == 'flemington'){
document.getElementById("inventorydisplay").innerHTML = '<?php echo $flemingtoninv; ?>';
}
else if (inventorychoice == 'default'){
document.getElementById("inventorydisplay").innerHTML = '<?php echo $defaultinv; ?>';   
}
}
</script>

<select onChange="selectinventory()" id="selection" name="selection">
<option value="flemington">Flemington</option>
<option value="default">Default</option>
</select>

<tr id="inventorydisplay">

<?php echo $inventorychoice; ?>

</tr>
```

I am getting an error saying "selectinventory is not defined" but it is clearly defined. When I remove the php script from the js function it removes the error but I need to echo the php through the javascript function.

Comment: you are saying you want the value from `php` but getting `inventorychoice` from `javascript`,  value of `$inventorychoice` want in javascript variable?

Comment: Show code which you get at page. It will be much more ease to help you ( view page source and put it here )

Comment: You really don't need (or even want to) *echo the php through the javascript function*.

Comment: $flemingtoninv = '
<td>3/4 Spray Jacket</td><td><textarea id="34sj" name="34sj" class=""></textarea></td><td><input id="34sjquantity" class="number" name="34sjquantity" type="number"></td></tr>
<tr><td>Shirt</td><td><textarea id="shirt" name="shirt" class=""></textarea></td><td><input id="shirtquantity" class="number" name="shirtquantity" type="number"></td></tr>
<tr><td>Black Waiters Jacket</td><td><textarea id="blackwj" name="blackwj" class=""></textarea></td><td><input id="blackwjquantity" class="number" name="blackwjquantity" type="number"></td></tr> ?>  The list for $defaultinv is similar

Comment: You will want to escape the text you are setting as the variable before you echo it out. PHP addslashes() http://us2.php.net/addslashes

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
<script>
function selectinventory()
{
var inventorychoice = document.getElementById("selection").value;
if (inventorychoice == 'flemington')
{
    document.getElementById("inventorydisplay").innerHTML = <?php echo "$flemingtoninv"; ?>;
}
else if (inventorychoice == 'default')
{
    document.getElementById("inventorydisplay").innerHTML = <?php echo "$defaultinv"; ?>;   
}
}
</script>
```

Comment: Tried that, still encountering the same problem "selectinventory is not defined" NOTE: when I remove the echo php variable the javascript function works.

Comment: That's because you must have a js error. Can you post the html output of the function from your browser?

Comment: In console I get the following when I change the select options. Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined inventory.php:19 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ; inventory.php:29 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function bootstrap.js:29 Uncaught ReferenceError: selectinventory is not defined inventory.php:206 –

Comment: But what about the html output of the selectinventory function?

Comment: The echo has be be escaped with slashes. `<?php echo addslashes($flemingtoninv); ?>`